# How to read a wsdl file in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

What is the appropriate way to interact/read a .wsdl file in C#? As in, what objects should I be using, etc.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The answer pretty much depends on what you want to do with this file.

Comment: is it fair to say i am not entirely sure?! we have an intrnal webservice that provides access to some data, we only want specific parts of this so instead of calling the full service we are just going to call parts defined in the wsdl file :/

Comment: So you want to cut the WSDL down before generating a service wrapper to call it? Unless you're desperate to reduce the generated code side it'd be simpler to just use the full WSDL and ignore the parts you don't need.

Comment: sorry for the vague question, its hard to be precise when i am not sure mysefl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment you don't need programatic access therefore the answer to the actual question is not what you need. You need the tools to generate code to call a Web Service. It is done by right clicking on references in the Visual Studio project and selecting Add Service Reference. There you give the URL of the WSDL or the WSDL file. The tool will generate proxy classes for web service calls. The Visual Studio UI I believe is just a GUI for a console tool called svcutil.exe (may be wrong on this).

On how to work with the actual client code just search for "calling SOAP web service with .NET" or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The [ServiceDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.description.servicedescription.aspx) class provides support for reading, modifying and writing WSDL files.

Answer (score 0):

You can read it like an XML file so with DOM or SAX. But if you intend to connect to a specific webservices you should generate the proxy class (with the Visual studio wizard or with wsdl.exe).